# fputcsv() outputs "Array" rather than contents of the array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to set up a simple feedback form which both emails us the user's responses and also saves them to a unique CSV file for later use.

One of the questions, "Favourites" can have multiple responses, so in the HTML form the checkboxes are all named 'favourites[]' and I have no problem outputting all selected options in the email by using a loop, but when fputcsv() interprets the _POST data, the contents of "Favourites" simply reads "Array."

Is there a simple way to make fputcsv() concatenate all selected responses and output them together in the CSV file?

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
      $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $first_time = $_POST['first_time'];
  $num_visits = $_POST['num_visits'];
  $recommend = $_POST['recommend'];
  $all_favs = '';
  foreach($_POST['favourites'] as $favourites) {
    $all_favs = $all_favs . ' ' . $favourites . ',';
  }
  $quality = $_POST['quality'];
  $presentation = $_POST['presentation'];
  $service = $_POST['service'];
  $cleanliness = $_POST['cleanliness'];
  $speed = $_POST['speed'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments'];
  $vdate = $_POST['vdate'];
  $method = $_POST['method'];
  $from = $email;
  $subject = 'New feedback from ' . $name . "";

 //create CSV to mail
$filename="collect/" . $vdate . $email . ".csv"; //specify filename and path
$keys=array_keys($_POST);     //get list of post keys       
$file=fopen($filename,"w");   //open a csv file to write to;
fputcsv($file,$keys);         //write post keys as first line of CSV file.
fputcsv($file,$_POST);        //write post data as second line of csv file.
fclose($file);                //close the file.
```

Comment: `$_POST['favourites'] = implode(',', $_POST['favourites']);`

Comment: Btw., your code is dangerous, because you use unchecked user input to create the file name. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal